# Take only the first hashmap value

Tags: java, android

I have a hashmap where I register three photos in firebase. Now I need to get only the first photo from the node to put in the ImageView of the adapter. But it seems to be coming in random.
Cadastrar.java

```
private HashMap<String, Object> fotosSelecionadas = new HashMap<>();
fotosSelecionadas.put(foto.getIdFoto(), foto);
pet.setFotos(fotosSelecionadas);
pet.salvar();
```

Adapter.java

```
HashMap<String, Object> urlFotos = pet.getFotos();
Object firstValue = urlFotos.values().iterator().next();
Picasso.get().load(String.valueOf(firstValue)).into(holder.foto);
```

Realtime Database

```
fotos
-MiLS77rQlWEEoZKeBfm
idFoto:"-MiLS77rQlWEEoZKeBfm"
urlFoto:"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/enc..."
-MiLS78o9Nagri_mR7WL
idFoto:"-MiLS78o9Nagri_mR7WL"
urlFoto:"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/enc..."
-MiLS79mdjV2JGFRWI0O
idFoto:"-MiLS79mdjV2JGFRWI0O"
urlFoto: 
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/enc..."
```

Comment: The entries in a `HashMap` are **not** ordered. (They are in a [LinkedHashMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedHashMap), though.) So what do you mean by _the first path_? Can you [edit] your question and post the path you want to get (based on the sample map in your question)?

Comment: The question does not make sense as written.  What do you mean by "the first path(https) of each"?   Each what?  And what is the real type of the values in the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("one", "壱");
    map.put("two", "弐");
    map.put("three", "参");
    map.put("four", "四");

    System.out.println("hash map = " + map);

    Object firstValue = map.values().iterator().next();

    System.out.println("first value = " + firstValue);
}
```

output:

```
hash map = {four=四, one=壱, two=弐, three=参}
first value = 四
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use `Java String class substring() method`.

IIUC, You want to get the string of `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/encontre-seu-pet-5f9bd.appspot.com/o/imagens%2Fpets%2F-MiF1htaqk2dztzB3v1U%2F-MiF1huwXv3f7H3LZ3bT?alt=media&token=97a9c87e-c875-4e6a-bc70-f7f656d40a50` ?

- get the first character index of `=` and `}`
- `String.substring(** ='s_index ** , ** }'s_index + 1 **)`

Comment: Possibly.  But that may not be what the OP means.  And there is a probably a *better* way to get it ... if we knew the actual type of the object that the OP called `valueOf` on.